# UICollectionViewCell loads late when I get the number of cells from an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My collection view cells loads late when I try to get number of cells from an array. This is how I get the number of friends of the current user:

```
var friendsList = [String]()

func countObserver() {

    CURRENT_USER_FRIENDS_REF.observe(.value, with: { snap in
        for child in snap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
        let id  = child.key
        self.friendsList.append(id)
        }
        print(self.friendsList.count)
    })


}
```

and then I do this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friendsList.count

}
```

It just loads like a second after the view appears on the screen. When I try a number like `return 5` it loads instantly. Is there any way I can load them instantly after I get the counts of users from database? I tried to get the number in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but it didn't change anything. And I am using firebase database

Comment: It looks like you are not calling `.reloadData()` on the collection view once you retrieved the `id`. Have you tried `self.collectionView.reloadData()` right after the `print` statement in the block?

Comment: @ozgur yea, just tried it. Still loads like a 0.5  second late